# Hash a byte string

Tags: c, hash, byte, hashtable

I'm working on a personal project, a file compression program, and am having trouble with my symbol dictionary. I need to store previously encountered byte strings into a structure in such a way that I can quickly check for their existence and retrieve them. I've been operating under the assumption that a hash table would be best suited for this purpose so my question will be pertaining to hash functions. However, if someone can suggest a better alternative to a hash table, I'm all ears.
All right. So the problem is that I can't come up with a good hashing key for these byte strings. Everything I think of either has a very uneven distribution, or is takes too long. Here is a list of the situation I'm working with:

1. All byte strings will be at least
   two bytes in length.
2. The hash table will have a maximum size of 3839, and it is very likely it will fill.
3. Testing has shown that, with any given byte, the highest order bit is significantly less likely to be set, as compared to the lower seven bits.
4. Otherwise, bytes in the string can be any value from 0 - 255 (I'm working with raw byte-data of any format).
5. I'm working with the C language in a UNIX environment. I'd prefer to stick with standard libraries, but it doesn't need to be portable to other OSs. (I.E. unistd.h is fine).
6. Security is of NO concern.
7. Speed is of a HIGH concern.
8. The size isn't of intense concern, as it will NOT be written to file. However, considering the potential size of the byte strings being stored, memory space could become an issue during the compression.

Comment: "Everything I think of" -- Instead of doing that, you might consider googling "hash function"; there are extensive references available online.

Comment: @Jim, Instead of thinking? Did you seriously just suggest Google as an alternative to thinking?

Comment: @Blindy I suggested drawing upon the wealth of human knowledge instead of trying to reinvent the wheel from the limits of personal effort. The entire history of software engineering (and human culture, for that matter) is about leverage of what is already available. *Thinking* would lead you to understand that instead of caricaturing what I wrote. And ironically, your own answer reflects that -- surely you didn't invent tries, and Paul would not have thought of them merely by going through everything he could think of.

Comment: P.S. http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html is a fine example of what googling can get you that *mere* thinking cannot. Of course, *given* that prior work, one can apply a lot of thinking to it, but to eschew research and just settle for what one can think of on one's own is incompetent, unprofessional, and unproductive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is better suited to this kind of thing because it lets you store your symbols as a tree and quickly parse it to match values (or reject them).

And as a bonus, you don't need a hash at all. You're storing/retrieving/comparing the entire sequence at once, while still only holding a minimal amount of memory.

Edit: And as an additional bonus, with only a second parse, you can look up sequences that are "close" to your current sequence, so you can get rid of a sequence and use the previous one for both of them, with some internal notation to hold the differences. That will help you compress files better because:

1. smaller dictionary means smaller files, you have to write the dictionary to your file
2. smaller number of items can free up space to hold other, more rare sequences if you add a population cap and you hit it with a large file.

Comment: Nice answer! Good point on not needing a hash. Perhaps if Paul can store the data as a number instead of a string, he might have an ordered list and do binary searches on it.

Comment: I actually don't have to write the dictionary to file; I'm using the LZW compression scheme. However, a trie does sound appealing. I'm gonna give it a shot.